# Combining Extension Library controls (Names\Value Picker) with Bootstrap - UI issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using Bootstrap withing my XPages project and I'm trying to add some Names Picker and Value Picker from Extension Library.

The issue I have is with CSS since OneUI is not being loaded within my Theme; this makes modal dialog to be displayed with no real format.

Has anyone been able to fix this?

For Dialog controls; I'm using Mark Leusink workaround:
http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/dialog.xsp

[image: Names Picker from ExtLib]

Comment: I have done a lot with Bootstrap modals.  Is is possible for you to add a screenshot to your question so I can understand what is happening.

Comment: Using a modal to populate a single field is (if you'll pardon the pun) an outmoded pattern anyway. Bind a Select2 instance to a REST service instead.

Comment: @TimTripcony I'm also using Select2 within my app which is a great implementation; where I'm planing to use ExtLib is for Names Picker, but, the issue is in general with any Dialog from ExtLib (Value Picker for example)

Comment: @SteveZavocki, I just uploaded a printsreen.

Comment: Picture>1000 words.  Can you now add the code you use to launch the modal.  Also, does the modal work if you take out picker control?  If it does, then look for the z-index in your CSS and make it really high.  If it doesn't work then get the modal working first, and then add the control.

Comment: @Steve I don't have a modal window, what I have is a simple XPage and next to the multivalue field I dragged a Names Picket from ExtLib. I don't have a CSS with any custom class at this point.

Comment: I guess my point is, if you're using Bootstrap and Select2, *don't* use the Name Picker and Value Picker components; use Select2 bound to a REST service to give the user typeahead instead of a dialog. And anywhere else where you would otherwise use a dialog component, use Bootstrap's implementation of a modal instead.

Comment: I agree with Tim: from a UX perspective, Select2 would be a better approach. At the bottom of [this](http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/select2.xsp) page you'll find an example using a remote data source (query in a database). That being said: there will probably be a new release of the [Bootstrap4XPages](http://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org) plugin that will render these dialogs automatically in the correct Bootstrap 3 style.

Comment: @TimTripcony, Mark Leusing great suggestion, especially if you are making an application 'Responsive' for mobile access. Just wondering if anyone of you have used REST Service from ExtLib with Select2 who can share an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I found out the classes used for the dialog and added it to my CSS file.

This is working for me:

```css
.dijitDialog {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding:5px;
}

.dijitDialogTitleBar {
    padding: 9px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
    cursor: move;
}

.dijitDialogTitle {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
}

.dijitDialogCloseIcon .closeText {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.2;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.dijitDialogUnderlayWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 998;
    display: none;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% black !important;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Comment: Works great; sometimes DialogBox or controls from ExtLib are handy so is good to have them available for Bootsrap.

Answer (score 0):

Just add from above's CSS style to make the X icon cursor pointer instead of move

```
.dijitDialogCloseIcon
{
    cursor:pointer
}
```